# Rails: import timestamps, different time zones and daylight saving time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got the task to import multiple data to an rails app. All data in the old database is stored with a timestamp of the actual GERMANY time at this date. I want to save now in UTC.

Example, in Database Germany dates are stored as:

1. 2013-06-01 10:44:00
2. 2013-11-01 10:44:00

Would be correct in UTC and should be in my Rails database as:

1. 2013-06-01 08:44:00
2. 2013-11-01 09:44:00

Because on 1st June it is CEST in Germany which is UTC+2, on 1st Nov it is CET in Germany which is UTC+1.

**No my problem**: I know how to tell Ruby the time zone, but what about daylight saving time?

```
Time.parse ’#{timestamp} CEST’
```

would result in

1. Time.parse ’2013-06-01 10:44:00 CEST’
   would be correct and correctly save the time as 08:44 UTC in my database
2. Time.parse ’2013-11-01 10:44:00 CEST’
   would also save this as 08:44 UTC – which is WRONG, should be 09:44 ...

Which is kind of understandable because I tell Ruby, the Date on 1st of Nov is in CEST which of course is false, its CET. (using Time.parse '... CET' would also result wrong the other way).

**HOW** can I tell Ruby to determine automatically which time zone to use according daylight saving time?

***Something like Time.parse ’#{timestamp} GERMANY’ possible?***

Otherwise I would need to check -> IF between 30 March and 26 Oct use CEST, else CET – which seems much to complicate for me...

Any help much appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a region has DST or not is encoded in the time zone.

Make sure you set `Time.zone` and then parse it using Rails' [Time.zone.parse](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse). Here's an example you can try in a Rails console:

```
> Time.zone = 'Berlin'
=> "Berlin"
> Time.zone.parse('2014-05-21 08:09:10')
=> Wed, 21 May 2014 08:09:10 CEST +02:00
> Time.zone.parse('2014-11-21 08:09:10')
=> Fri, 21 Nov 2014 08:09:10 CET +01:00
```

You can see that the same time is parsed with a different offset, depending on whether it's within DST or not.

Comment: That was incredible fast, simple and correct - and is working! Thanks a lot!